# How to get by throwing query in nest.js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

In my `controller.ts`

```
  @Get()
  getFuga(@Query() query: { place: string }): string {
    return query.place
  }
```

When I throw `query` via `GET`

`http://localhost:3000/event?place=Tokyo`

the response is `Tokyo`

I'd like to get the result by querying like

`select * from events where events.place = 'Tokyo'`

Are there any good way to achieve connecting `DB` and throw query ?

As I am beginner, if some useful material exist,can I reach out?

```
mysql> select * from events;
+----+--------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
| id | title  | date       | place   | detail | is_lastdate | begin_time | end_time | label_cd | created_at                 | updated_at                 | deleted_at | user_id |
+----+--------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
|  1 | mytest | 2000-12-31 | Tottori | test   |           1 | 11:59:00   | 23:40:00 |        4 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.834987 | 2020-10-04 13:08:29.000000 | NULL       |    NULL |
|  2 | mytest | 2000-12-31 | Tokyo   | test   |           1 | 11:59:00   | 23:40:00 |        4 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.834987 | 2020-10-04 13:08:19.000000 | NULL       |    NULL |
|  3 | mytest | 2020-07-06 | Tokyo   | test   |           0 | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00 |        0 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.834987 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.901008 | NULL       |    NULL |
|  4 | mytest | 2020-07-06 | Tokyo   | test   |           0 | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00 |        0 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.834987 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.901008 | NULL       |    NULL |
|  5 | mytest | 2000-12-31 | Tokyo   | NULL   |           0 | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00 |        0 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.834987 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.901008 | NULL       |    NULL |
|  6 | mytest | 2000-12-31 | Tokyo   | NULL   |           0 | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00 |        0 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.834987 | 2020-10-04 02:46:05.901008 | NULL       |    NULL |
|  7 | mytest | 2000-12-31 | Tokyo   | NULL   |           0 | 00:00:00   | 00:00:00 |        0 | 
+----+--------+------------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Use ```typeorm``` or any kind of ORM that suits you. It should be easy to query using ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Typeorm](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) which is most widely used [ORM](https://blog.bitsrc.io/what-is-an-orm-and-why-you-should-use-it-b2b6f75f5e2a)
in nestjs to connect to various databases.
Once you integrate it in your project you can use query builder or active record which are Typeorm query styles in order to get the result as you want.